# Difference between two tar commands -cf and -Jchf

Tags: tar, 7z, p7zip

I have a python script that is running in two places, two different, but similar commands:

```
os.system("tar cf - -C %s . 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null | 7za a -p%s -si %s 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null" % (cf, self.config.get(jn, "archpass"), filename))


os.system("tar -Jchf - -C %s . 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null | 7za a -p%s -si %s 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null" % (cf, self.config.get(jn, "archpass"), filename))
```

This script is used to backup websited on a Ubuntu server. So most of files are html/php/js/jpg.
I need to understand this command more in order to have an idea if there is place for improvement.

**Question 1)** What's the difference between: `tar cf` and `tar -Jchf`.
Unfortunately `tar --help` didn't help me understand the additional `-Jf` parameters.

**Question 2)** Is tar also archiving? What could be the purpose of sending everything to `7za`? Is it doing a double archivisation?

Comment: Some bad practice (passwords in arguments) and command injection vulnerabilities in there. I wouldn't trust a software with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual difference in the commands are the `Jh` switches, which are described here (from `man tar`):

```
-h, --dereference
              Follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to.
-J, --xz
              Filter the archive through xz(1).
```

So you're forcing the archive to be compressed with `xz` and following symlinks instead of archiving the links themselves.

Comment: thank you, what about the question 2?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 7za so I can't comment. If it is a compression utility, then the -J switch seems redundant.

Comment: Yes, using -J and 7za together is redundant and unproductive.  It is trying to compress a compressed stream, which isn't going to help.

Comment: thank you both.